# Web Scraping - Requests ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(60, 'ETIMEDOUT')",))

Tags: python, python-requests, web-scripting

I'm trying to access to a webpage. I tried 'UserAgent' to add headers, however, got timeout error:
my new codes:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import requests

url = "https://www.bestbuy.com/site/lg-65-class-oled-b9-series-2160p-smart-4k-uhd-tv-with-hdr/6360611.p?skuId=6360611"
ua = UserAgent()
print(ua.chrome)
header = {'User-Agent':str(ua.chrome)}
print(header)
url_get = requests.get(url, headers=header)
print(url_get)
```

--> 285                 raise SocketError(str(e))
    286         except OpenSSL.SSL.ZeroReturnError as e:

OSError: (60, 'ETIMEDOUT')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    439                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 440                     timeout=timeout
    441                 )

--> 285                 raise SocketError(str(e))
    286         except OpenSSL.SSL.ZeroReturnError as e:

ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(60, 'ETIMEDOUT')",))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont to need use fake_useragent , just try some like this ...pass  agent cookies variable to request

```
import requests

url = "https://www.bestbuy.com/site/lg-65-class-oled-b9-series-2160p-smart-4k-uhd-tv-with-hdr/6360611.p?skuId=6360611"
agent = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36'}
cookies = {"cookie":"COPY_HERE_YOUR_COOKIE_FROM_BROWSER"}
url_get = requests.get(url,headers=agent, cookies=cookies)
print(url_get.text)
```

If you dont know how get the cookies , just click right in your browser (Chrome example) -> Inspect > Network ...and when you load the web look the first request and look the headers.
This code work for me.